# How to invoke javascript function on web page from chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

There is a web site with this snippet in every page:

```js
var refreshSite; 
refreshSiteInterval();
function refreshSiteInterval() {
  refreshSite = setInterval(
    function() { document.location = document.location; }, 
    420000);
};
function stopRefreshSite() {
  clearInterval(refreshSite);
}
```

Calling `stopRefreshSite()` from javascript console stops the timed refresh from occurring.

I'd like to disable this recurring refresh with a chrome extension. I thought that a content script which calls `stopRefreshSite()` whenever the page loads makes sense, though because content scripts execute in an *isolated world* this doesn't seem to be possible.

Is there any way to call the webpage function? Or would trying to prevent the original javascript from running in the first place be a better strategy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To execute script on the page, you have to insert a `script` element into it, which is easily done and covered in this answer: [*Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879).

In your case:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = "stopRefreshSite()";
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
```

Comment: ...although I can't immediately see any reason for preferring `document.head` over just using `document.documentElement`.

Comment: I've added the script with "run_at": "document_end" and while the script is definitely running, I can't find the injected script element. I'm starting to debug...

Comment: @DavidResnick: Note the last line of the above. :-) We're removing it after adding it, since it's adding it that runs the code it contains. You could take that line out if you like.

Comment: Yeah, I scratched my head looking at that... ;) Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: `script.remove()`

Comment: @Legends: On *modern* browsers *today*, yeah. Not on (say) IE11. I'm not even sure what support was like in 2015.